# Looking for application which will provide to determine project database growth and cost per day or month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-projects

I am using SQL Server 2008 for product development

Currently application is live with 20 users now if I want to check how my database is growing and how much it will grow in month or year projection to determine the cost of hardware. Is there any application or SQL Server built-in function?

Using SQL Server profiler I am able to monitor database queries and fine tuning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use a third party tool [Idera Diagnostic Manager](https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqldiagnosticmanager) to identify the growth and cost. There is a report inbuilt which forecast database and table growth depending upon how much historical data it has.
2. You can also set up this with the help of combination of TSQL + Powershell as described [Database Space Capacity Planning](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/powershell/68011/) by chad. It will help you in analyzing the database growth.
3. You can also see the Brent Ozar's answer on this as a solution as well

[Estimate projected database growth](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72320/estimate-projected-database-growth)

Answer (score 2):

`exec sp_helpdb` gives you the size of each database. You can create a table `dbsize` and do `insert into dbsize exec sp_helpdb` to insert data into it once a week using a job. After a month, you can see how much each db grew

Comment: this is more manually and we need to predict it based on the our data :)